# Finding the Max of another Max query

Tags: sql, max

I have a table of data that looks like follows:

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| Client | Item No. | Serial No. |
+--------+----------+------------+
| A      |        1 |          1 |
| A      |        1 |          2 |
| B      |        1 |          2 |
| B      |        2 |          1 |
| C      |        2 |          3 |
| C      |        2 |          2 |
| C      |        3 |          1 |
| C      |        3 |          2 |
| D      |        2 |          3 |
| D      |        2 |          1 |
| D      |        3 |          2 |
| D      |        3 |          3 |
| D      |        2 |          2 |
| D      |        3 |          1 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

What I'm looking to do is find for each client the highest **Item No.** followed by highest **Serial No.** (in that order). So for the above the output would be:

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| Client | Item No. | Serial No. |
+--------+----------+------------+
| A      |        1 |          2 |
| B      |        2 |          1 |
| C      |        3 |          2 |
| D      |        3 |          3 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

I'm thinking this will require a nested MAX() statement, to first get the **MAX(Item No.)** for each client and for those with multiple then get the **MAX(Serial No.)** What's an efficient way to write this query?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? MySQL?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT t.client,
       t.item,
       MAX(t.serial) AS serial
  FROM(SELECT client,
              MAX(item) AS item
         FROM your_table
        GROUP
           BY client
      ) a
  JOIN your_table t
    ON a.client = t.client AND a.item = t.item
 GROUP
    BY t.client, t.item
```

If your DBMS supports window functions, another way would be:

```
SELECT client, item, serial
  FROM(SELECT client, item, serial,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client ORDER BY item DESC, serial DESC) rn
         FROM your_table
      )
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Great solution, I was wondering if there was something available like the window function you mention. In terms of performance does the Window function work better?

Comment: The Windowing version will be _much_ better unless the query optimizer understands the long version and does the same thing. There should be an EXPLAIN feature to compare query plans.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has the awesome shortcut

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Client) Client, Item, SerialNumber
FROM some_table
ORDER BY Item DESC, SerialNumber DESC -- DESC gets highest
```

Because of the DISTINCT this grabs only one record per Client, and the ORDER BY makes sure it is the ones you want.

I have no idea if any other DBMSs will do this so easily.

Comment: Yes i was hoping something like this would work but not in MS SQL. Closest way to get the same is per the OVER clause as shown in DirkNM's response. Same idea, returns just the row number you specify, in this case 1.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Client, MAX(Item_No) AS  Item_No
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY Client)

SELECT a.Client,b.Item_No,MAX(Serial_No) AS Serial_No 
FROM CTE a
JOIN YourTable b ON a.Client = b.Client AND a.Item_No = b.Item_No
GROUP BY a.Client,b.Item_No
```